# How to Load Typeface using InputStream

Tags: android, typeface

How can i load the Typeface using InputStream?

I am using classLoader to to the resource and it will return an Inputstream, now how to pass it to Typeface?

I have tried with these methods:

```
font  = Typeface.createFromFile(line); //File path

font  = Typeface.createFromFile(line);//String path
```

But both of them will not work.

Is there any other way that i can acheive this?

Comment: http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.in/2012/01/using-custom-font-in-android.html

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks can you please explain what he is doing?

Comment: @user2056563 Creating a file in External storage and then giving the file path to createFromFile() method

Answer (score 2):

The closest you'll get is to save the stream out to a (temporary) file, and pass that file to the method.